# Code to solve simultaneous modular equations?

Tags: c++, c, math, equation

Here the symbol = is used to mean "is congruent to"

If

```
(1) n = a mod j
(2) n = b mod k
```

Then

```
(3) n = c mod l
```

Basically, given the first two equations, find the third. For my purposes, I know in advance that a solution exists.

I would like some code in C or C++ to do this for me, or a link to a library or something that I can use in a C/C++ project. Thanks.

Comment: as written you appear to have too many unknowns and not enough equations to solve that system...

Comment: @Mark: Probably `n` and `c` are the only unknowns.  That might still be too many unknowns if `j`, `k`, and `l` are relatively prime.

Comment: I can see I was a bit unclear here: n, a, b, j and k are all known. The only unknowns are c and l. Sorry about that.

Comment: OK, my mistake again. n is unknown as well. Basically I'm looking for something that uses the CRT where applicable but if not then just solves it using simultaneous equations or some other clever way. The reason I want the code rather than writing it myself is that I'm sure that by now someone would have written it in some kind of highly optimised form, possibly using techniques I'm unfamiliar with. I can add an example to the question if anything is still unclear. Thanks for persisting.

Comment: OK, if n is unknown, and a solution is known to exist, the problem makes a lot more sense.  I'll assume you're looking for a CRT-like solution where L is going to be the least common multiple of j and k (or jk, if gcd(j,k) = 1).  Any non-brute-force solution is going to come down to something like the CRT method, and make heavy use of Euclid's algorithm.  I'll try to expand on my answer a bit if I can find the time.

Answer (score 5):

If a, b, j, and k are given, l = jk, and gcd(j,k) = 1, then c can be found using the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).  (If j and k have a nontrivial GCD, the solution c may or may not exist.)

Answer (score 1):

A library to represent infinite arithmetic sequences would be useful here, but I don't personally know any. Regardless, here is a brute force solution that basically generates possibilities for `n` from each given modular equation and finds the intersection. It finds the lowest value of `n` by "leap-frogging" (pseudo-code):

```
value_left := a
value_right := b

while value_left != value_right:
    if value_left < value_right:
        value_left := value_left + j
    else:
        value_right := value_right + k
    end if
end while loop

return value_left % l // as in "leggo-mah-eggo!"
```

Let me know if you would like actual C code, although the translation should be fairly straightforward.